# Made changes to the code while the app is running

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I'm talking about small changes in the code of a method, without changing the signature, parameters or returned type.

Is it possible to do that with Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 on .Net Core 3.1, and higher, projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET 6 will have Hot Reload support for ASP.NET Core/Blazor web apps. .NET Hot Reload applies code changes to your running app without restarting it and without losing the app state.

The most recent .NET 6 Preview has initial support for it.

> To try out hot reload with an existing ASP.NET Core project based on
> .NET 6, add the "hotReloadProfile": "aspnetcore" property to your
> launch profile in launchSettings.json. For Blazor WebAssembly
> projects, use the "blazorwasm" hot reload profile.
>
> Run the project using `dotnet watch`.

You can find [details for this kind of apps here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-3/).

In addition, .NET Hot Reload will be supported with WPF, WinUI, WinForms apps in future preview releases of .NET 6. Visual Studio [will also support this technology](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6-preview-3/).

Unfortunately, this tool is not available for previous .NET versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit an continue while debugging, if that's what you mean:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-edit-and-continue-csharp?view=vs-2019